# Как перезаписать файл UNIX?

Tags: unix

Есть код, нужно перезаписать результат в этот же файл

```
exec ('sort -u -b -n 1.txt > uTest_1.txt');
```

Сейчас перезаписывает в uTest_1.txt, а нужно в 1.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вело

```
exec ('sort -u -b -n 1.txt > uTest_1.txt && mv uTest_1.txt 1.txt');
```